# Unit test only fails in maven, not iIntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I'm hitting a weird issue were my unit tests fail when running `mvn install` but they pass when running in IntelliJ.

I've looked at posts online about debugging maven, but I don't want to debug maven itself, or a maven plugin. I want to debug my unit tests when they have been called by maven. More specifically, I want to debug my code but using the Junit tests as an entry point for the debugging via a breakpoint.

Hope that makes sense.

My issue is relating to using introspection to look at some classes the application is importing from another project. This succeeds when the project is running or running in debug mode, but fails when maven runs the tests as a part of an install. i.e. the code doesn't find the classes in the other project when running under maven...

As this application uses multiple maven projects that all need to be installed, I've had to move my unit tests out into another project just so that the installs don't fail and I can carry on development.

However, for obvious reasons I would like to put my unit tests in each individual project, so am very keen to debug this and find out what is failing.

My project is called infinite-state-machine and can be found here - https://github.com/museadmin/infinite-state-machine

The unit tests are currently in their own project here - https://github.com/museadmin/infinite-state-machine-test

If anyone can advise me how to run maven in debug mode and attach IntelliJ to it so that I can set a breakpoint in my failing unit tests I will be forever in their debt :)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Brad

Comment: Why are your unit tests in a different project? Why not within the original project? This is the practise to put unit tests into the same project as where the code can be found? Furthermore it would helpful which kind of message/error you get?

Comment: Start the tests in debug mode per https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html. In IntelliJ IDEA use [Remote Debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html) to connect to the maven VM running the tests.

Comment: Select the test in IDEA and run in Debug mode not via surefire/maven ...

Comment: This is the result of haven the tests in a different project which makes no sense to me.

Comment: @khmarbaise did you actually read the question? Debugging/running works in IntelliJ IDEA, he asked how to debug the problem with the command line Maven running outside of the IDE.

Comment: ok than start at my first post: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Thanks guys. I had a feeling I'd get loads of responses about the tests being in the wrong place. Even though I made it clear that I too didn't want them there. I guess this is a difficult situation to get your head around. I've now fixed the issue without debugging. But I'd still like to know how how attach the debugger to my unit tests when they're running under maven as part of the install phase. So I'll check the links you provided crazycoder. Thanks